# delete multiple messages in telegram bot

Tags: laravel, bots, telegram, botman

I am using laravel + botman for create telegram bot.
I want to delete multiple messages not one by one. Because it take a lot of time.
is it possible to delete multiple messages at onces

Comment: Can you show your code which you've tried?

Comment: `for($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++)
{
     $this->bot->sendRequest('deleteMessage', ['chat_id'=>$chat_id, 'message_id'=>$i]);
}`